# SQL Get data from time duration

Tags: c#, sql

I have a SQL database in which I have a column with DataType DateTime. Now I want particular data with particular time duration of all dates.
For example, I want data between 7 o'clock and 8 o'clock from all dates, is there any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For SQL Server, you can do:

```
select *
from MyTable
where datepart(hour, MyDateColumn) between 19 and 20
```

For MySQL:

```
select *
from MyTable
where EXTRACT(HOUR FROM MyDateColumn) between 19 and 20
```